# persistence or serialization from java to C# Best way to send this object by TCP/IP

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

what is the best way to serialize an object from Android Java and send to another computer by TCP and then to deserialize in C#?

I originally wanted to use Java serialization, however i hear that i will not be able to deserialize the same file in C# on the other computer.

can i do this with google's gson library?  it converts any Java object into JSON string.  or is XML better, like using Xstream library an option?

the object is vary simple, it contains only one string and a SQLite Database object and will be sent by TCP/IP sockets from the Android tablet to the desktop computer running windows 7.

i have no experience with C# or .NET, any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to send? A small object or a huge tree of several objects, datastructures,...?

Comment: vary small object, only short string and a database file SQLite database

Comment: And you don't want to call methods at the `C#` or `Java` side, who should be executed at the other side?

Comment: i am just transporting a database file from android tablet to a desktop computer so it can update the SQLite database file and send it back later.  the textfile is so the server can identify which tablet the database file belongs to

Comment: You could use socket programming or a broker like EJB or CORBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of my projects, I have used Google ProtoBuf format for this.
http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

ProtoBuf is a highly compact and efficient format. It supports C# and Java among many others.

Take a look at this article for details:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640249/Android-Fast-Communication-with-NET-Using-Protocol